# Changing "this" inside prototype context to replace function body

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was just wondering if it was possible to change a function body inside it's own prototype. Something like this:

```
Function.prototype.replace(newFun)
{
    this = newFun;
}
```

I receive **invalid left-hand side in assigment** error.
I want to achieve something like:

```
var fun1 = function(x, y)
{
   return x+y;
}

fun1.replace(Function(["x", "y"], "return x*y;"));
```

Is it possible in javascript? How can I do it?

Comment: Why not `fun1 = theNewFunction`?

Comment: Because I want to have a `replace` method for all my functions, and not only for fun1.

Comment: But the assignment operator `=` works for all functions, not only for `fun1`. Instead of `fun1.replace(newFun1); fun2.replace(newFun2)`, use `fun1 = newFun1; fun2 = newFun2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, functions are all [Function objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

It's possible to dynamically get a reference to the current function within its body with *arguments.callee*.

Unfortunately, Function objects have no setter methods. They are immutable. You would need to create your own mutable function class, which would contain a modifiable property containing a function.